# Android Studio: Failed to update SDK or SDK Tools

Tags: android

Android Studio (v2.2 Preview 3) suddenly failed to update the tools. It keeps giving the error pasted below:

***To install:
- LLDB 2.2 (lldb;2.2)
Preparing "Install LLDB 2.2".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Failed packages:
- LLDB 2.2 (lldb;2.2)***

I gave the folder full permissions. Ran android studio on administrator mode. End-tasked adb from task manager. Disabled antivirus. Deleted the folder and then ran the update again. But nothing works.

I also tried to create a new sdk location on my drive. But then that failed to, it gave the same error as above. **-> Failed to read or create install properties file.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26):

I also encountered the same error when trying to update build tools after upgrading Android Studio. Unfortunately, in my case, removing .AndroidStudio2.x folder and re-opened studio with no config imported didn't work.

But then inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774897/android-studio-google-repository-update-failing-failed-to-read-or-create-insta), I go to Android Studio folder, then to *bin* folder, right-clicked on *studio64.exe*, choose *Run as administrator*. Then when I tried to update the build tools, it worked.

I'll just leave it here as an alternative way in case someone encountered the same problem.

Comment: This is the workaround I normally use as well - but it is a "poor man's solution". Android Studio should ask for permissions when it wants to save something in the Applications directory, or it should not save anything there at all.

Answer (score 4):

For some reasons, this happens when you import the settings when upgrading Android Studio.

The fix is to delete the **.AndroidStudio2.1** or **.AndroidStudio2.2** folder in your profile directory.  Open android studio and don't import any config.

This will however will ask to download the supporting libraries again.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10, I pinned the application to my taskbar, and right-clicked on the icon and chose the option to run as administrator. Then I went through the steps to download my SDKs. Everything worked as it should.

Comment: If it worked as it should you wouldn't need to run it as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows7:  I unzipped the SDK under `C:\Program Files\...` but eventually discovered that security permissions in the "`Program Files`" area prevented `sdkmanager.bat` from creating folders and files.

It looks like you can give `sdkmanager.bat` permissions, but there are many complications, especially in `cmd`.

So I moved the SDK to `C:\Users\[admin_name]\.android` (or any folder) where it's easy for the `sdkmanger` to create folders and files and it finally worked !!

Hope this helps someone.  Thank-you to all those who have helped me.

Comment: This was useful information.  If you don't want to move files around, you can start a shell with administrative privileges and the update will work.

Comment: @jaime That's a workaround. No solution.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `sdkmanager` command in Linux, you have to run it as root:

```
sudo sdkmanager --install emulator
```

Answer (score 0):

On **Linux**, It's a permission issue. You can resolve the problem quickly by launching Android Studio as root :

```
gksudo <path_to_file_studio.sh>
```

If you want to fix this problem on long term and in more secure and better way you should find the right files / folder to alter and change their permissions. I didn't point it for now.

This solution was tested on Debian, but I guess it works on Unbuntu, Mint ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit local.properties it is a generated file, right click your project and select 'Open Module Settings' under SDK Location put your location for your SDK.

paste in  /Users/gururaj/Library/Android/sdk

Clean and rebuild your project

Update

Try to delete your local.properties file and create a new one, but do not check it into version control.

Right click top level of project and Create new file 'local.properties' then add: sdk.dir=/Users/gururaj/Library/Android/sdk

Clean and build

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to uninstall everything, delete the directories created in Program Files and Program Files (x86) and reinstall in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Currently using Jetbrains rider I had a similar issue. What worked for me, I  closed out Jetbrains and ran it as admin and it worked for me.