# Android Studio: Google repository update failing. Failed to read or create install properties file

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I am running an **Archlinux** system and my user account has read write permissions to the Android SDK and Android Studio folders under `/opt/`. I am getting these errors:

> [  76583]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/enlighter/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
>   [  77786]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'MyApplication' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
>               WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/enlighter/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

When I try to update the Google repositories to revision 36 from current 35, I get this error:

> WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed to read or create install properties file.

And update fails without even downloading the required files. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feels a bit wrong, but running AndroidStudio with sudo (sudo studio.sh) was the only thing that worked for me so far. You can try running only the sdk manager, this should work as well. This is required only for the SDK update. Regular usage of Android Studio doesn't require sudo.